# Rellenar Array Bidimensional

Tags: java, array

Como rellenar un array bidimensional para que luego quede, por ejemplo tal que:

```
   Michael Jordan – nº 23, 35 puntos, 6 rebotes y 3 robos.
   Charles Barckey – nº 32, 23 puntos, 12 rebotes y 1 robo.
```

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String [][] jugadores = new String[12][5];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < jugadores.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < jugadores[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Dime el nombre del jugador: ");
            jugadores[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Dime el número del jugador: ");
            jugadores[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Dime los puntos del jugador: ");
            jugadores[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Dime los robos del jugador: ");
            jugadores[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < jugadores.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < jugadores[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(jugadores[i][j] + " - nº " + jugadores[i][j] + ", " + jugadores[i][j] + " puntos," + jugadores[i][j] + " rebotes y " + jugadores[i][j] + " robos");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso específico el segundo for no te ayuda, debes hacerlo con un for

```
for(int i=0;i<jugadores.length();i++)
{
    System.out.println("Dime el nombre");
   jugadores[i][0] = sc.nextline();
   System.out.println("Dime número");
   jugadores[i][1] = sc.nextline();
   // y así sucesivamente para [i][2] hasta [i][n]

}
```

Y para imprimir lo mismo un solo ciclo

```
for(int i = 0; i<jugadores.length();i++)
{
   System.out.println("nombre");
   System.out.println(jugadores[i][0]);

   // Y así para todos los atributos del jugador con sus respectivos valores [i][n]
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Me ha servido de mucho, me estaba confundiendo mucho con el tema de los arrays bidimensionales al momento de rellenar y sacar información